# Search & Replace Using Grep and Sed Command

Tags: linux, php, grep, sed

I want to remove the weird / special characters from the bunch of text files. Here i used the following command to remove the weird characters but it gives me the error.

Command :

1) grep -lri -e Ã¢â¬Å temp.txt | xargs sed -i ' s_Ã¢â¬Å_"_g'

2) grep -lri -e Ã¢â¬Å temp.txt | xargs sed -i ' s/Ã¢â¬Å/"/g'

3) grep -lri -e Ã¢â¬Å temp.txt | xargs perl -piew ' s_Ã¢â¬Å_"_g'

4) grep -lri -e Ã¢â¬Å temp.txt | xargs perl -piew ' s/Ã¢â¬Å/"/g'

Here I want to replace Ã¢â¬Å this character with " quote.

These are the some Weird characters that I want to remove from the text files :

â€“ , â€” , ; , : , ! , Â¡ , Â¿ , Â· , â€š , â€¹ , â€º , Â» , @ , / , [ , ]\ ,
\^ , + , \ , \$ , \s , & , # , % , â€ , â€¡ , ` , Â´ , Â¯ , Ë˜ , Â¨ , Â§ , Â¶ ,
Â© , Â® , â„ , Â° , Âº , âˆ‚ , âˆ† , âˆ , âˆ‘ , Â± , = , â‰  , Â¬ , \ ,  , ~ ,
âˆ« , â‚¬ , Âª , Ã  , Ã¢ , Ã… , Ã¤ , Ã† , Ã‡ , Ã¨ , Ã« , ï¬ , ï¬‚ , Æ’ , Ã­ , Ã¬ ,
Ã® , Ã¯ , Ã³ , Ã² , Ã´ , Ã¶ , Ãµ , Ã¸ , Å“ , ÃŸ
and so on.

Please help me on this & Also suggest the command to remove the bunch of weird characters.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). [Same question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832990/search-replace-using-grep-and-sed-command).

Comment: Here I want to replace Ã¢â¬Å this character with " quote. likewise 1) ÃƒÂº with u (lower case letter u) 2) ÃƒÂµ with o (lower case letter o) 3) Ã­â€˜ with N (upper case letter N) 4) Ã­Â© with e (lower case letter e) 5) Ã­Âº with u (lower case letter u) –

Comment: @Thor I've already flagged this for closing on Stack Overflow as it's not really a… programming problem. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please post the actual file you want to work on. As @slhck suggested, this is likely an encoding problem and all you need to do is set the right encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The `perl` command can easily operate on a set of files. There's no need to `grep` the files to search them for a certain string, then pass those file names via a pipe to `xargs` and *then* to `perl`. This will definitely break even in the simple case that any of the files contain a spaces in their name.

Why not do the following, for example to remove invalid characters?

```
perl -pi -e 's/[â€”Ã‡…]//g' *.txt
```

Or, to remove non-ASCII characters:

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' *.txt
```

Or, to replace a certain character with another:

```
perl -pi -e 's/ÃƒÂº/u/g' *.txt
```

Comment: Here I want to replace Ã¢â¬Å this character with " quote. likewise 1) ÃƒÂº with u (lower case letter u) 2) ÃƒÂµ with o (lower case letter o) 3) Ã­â€˜ with N (upper case letter N) 4) Ã­Â© with e (lower case letter e) 5) Ã­Âº with u (lower case letter u)
So what is the command?

Comment: No need to copy-paste the same comment. To replace `Ã¢â¬Å` with a quote, use `s/Ã¢â¬Å/"/g`, et cetera. See: [Perl Text Patterns for Search and Replace](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html) — but actually, I'm pretty sure your problem is just that the file you have is improperly encoded, right? Wouldn't it be better to fix the overall character encoding? Where did you get the file from?

Comment: perl -pi -e 's/ÃƒÂº|â€š/u/g' *.txt

as like this i want to add multiple weird chjaracters to replace with some text

Comment: You can put multiple expression in the Perl command: `perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g; s/yak/yaz/g; s/…/…/g; …' *.txt`. No way around that, really, unless you want to write a script where you could put the replacment strings into an associative array of some sort. But that'd probably be overkill here.

Comment: ok
Also How can I use the regular expression?
Please give me the example.

Comment: There is no real regular expression here. If you want to look at examples of regular expressions (which aren't needed in your case), please look at the link I sent you three comments above. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the one regular expression
\A(?s)(^.+) \1
and want to replace with \1

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you need. The regular expression you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with your file and the replacing of unusual characters—it doesn't quite make sense to me either. If you have a new question unrelated to this one, please ask a new question.